# Move UIAlertView litle bit down in landscape mode in ios 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uialertview

```
alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Enter Student Name" message:@"" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Save", @"Save and Add", nil];
                alert.tag = 1;
                alert.alertViewStyle=UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
                [alert show];
```

its been working beautifully in potrait mode but in landscape my `UITextfield` going out of screen.and now i want to move a alertView frame a little bit down so that it will be visible .

[image]

Comment: You can't, it would then overlap the keyboard...

Comment: how about this cancel button behind keyboard ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't change any thing in the `UIAlertView` design in iOS7, you should use it as is, you have three chices here:

- Take off the cancel button (If i were you i would do this).
- Use a custom UIAlertView from [cocoacontrols.com](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/) and put the three buttons at the same line.
- Use another control like popover or modal.